# Use LINQ to Convert a List to a List of Lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of values:

```
IList<V> values = { V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7 };
```

I would like to convert the list into a list of lists, where each sub-list is a specified size. The size of each sub-list could vary.  For example:

```
IList<IList<V>> values_size2 = { { V1, V2 }, { V3, V4 }, { V5, V6 }, { V7 } };
IList<IList<V>> values_size3 = { { V1, V2, V3 }, { V4, V5, V6 }, { V7 } };
IList<IList<V>> values_size4 = { { V1, V2, V3, V4 }, { V5, V6, V7 } };
```

I could probably do this pretty easily using nested loops, but was wondering if there was a clever way to do this using LINQ?

My initial thought would be to use the [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) method somehow, but nothing comes to mind right away.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a generic `IEnumerable` based `Batch` function.  You can just change the return type from `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` to `IEnumerable<IList<T>>` with no other changes (since in my implementation it's already a list.  To change the whole thing to return a list of lists you'd need to either call `ToList on the result, or make a more involved refactor.

Note that technically this isn't using LINQ, it's just creating a new method that uses the same style and patterns commonly used by LINQ.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source
    , int batchSize)
{
    //TODO validate parameters

    List<T> buffer = new List<T>();

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        buffer.Add(item);

        if (buffer.Count >= batchSize)
        {
            yield return buffer;
            buffer = new List<T>();
        }
    }
    if (buffer.Count >= 0)
    {
        yield return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution is good, one thing I'd improved - setting buffer capacity to batch size when you create buffer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/) Batch extension (available from [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/morelinq)):

```
IList<IList<V>> values_size2 = values.Batch(2);
IList<IList<V>> values_size3 = values.Batch(3);
IList<IList<V>> values_size4 = values.Batch(4);
```

Also you can view sources [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs).

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize)
 {
     while (source.Any())
     {
         yield return source.Take(chunkSize);
         source = source.Skip(chunkSize);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I came across this in the wild and would advise against. I used it on a fairly large data set (over 100k) and it spiked my CPU. Something to do with the recursive `Skip()` I think? Appreciate the response though!

Answer (score 1):

With .NET 6 you can use the [new `Chunk` Linq method](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-4/#chunk)

```
List<IList<V>> values_size2 = values.Chunk(2).ToList();
List<IList<V>> values_size3 = values.Chunk(3).ToList();
List<IList<V>> values_size4 = values.Chunk(4).ToList();
```