# Split list just like string.split()

Tags: c#, linq, split

I want to split list just like `string.split(split_between_that_value)` does, how can I do this?

So with string `"some string with spaces"` string.Split(' ') will split it to `[some, string, with, spaces]` array.

But with list containing all characters as items I have no idea how to do it...

List:

`{'s','o','m','e',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g',' ','w','i','t','h',' ','s','p','a','c','e','s'}`

I want it to to split into list of lists:

`{{'s','o','m','e'},{'s','t','r','i','n','g'},{'w','i','t','h'},{'s','p','a','c','e','s'}}`

Comment: Is the list a List<string>?

Comment: @robert-m No my list is List<custom type>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough there is not an existing extension method that does this out of the box.  If you wanted a general solution (something that works for more than just `IEnumerable<char>`) you could implement it yourself with something like this:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IList<TSource>> Split<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        var list = new List<TSource>();

        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            if (predicate(element))
            {
                if (list.Count > 0)
                {
                    yield return list;
                    list = new List<TSource>();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(element);
            }
        }

        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return list;
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
var list = new List<char>(){'s','o','m','e',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g',' ','w','i','t','h',' ','s','p','a','c','e','s'};
list.Split(x => x == ' ')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this one can be done with native LINQ.

Comment: Check out this SO question on splitting a list into a list of lists. It looks like you can do it using pure LINQ but it might not be as efficient. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845650/use-linq-to-convert-a-list-to-a-list-of-lists

Comment: @BladeMight The last `if (list.Count > 0)` makes it a bit inconsistent compared to the `string.Split` behaviour in that `"a".Split` returns the same result as `"a ".Split`. I would either remove it to return all results, or add it to both `yield` to exclude empty entries.

Comment: @Slai - I agree that `if (list.Count . 0)` should have been added to the first `yield return`.  I realized that shortly after I posted the answer but, well, I guess I just did not care enough then to change it.  But it is fixed now.

Comment: The other answer and the linked answer did it too, but I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

I would write an extension method like

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, 
                                                        Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    using (var en = seq.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (en.MoveNext())
        {
            list.Add(en.Current);

            while (en.MoveNext())
            {
                if (condition(en.Current))
                {
                    list.Add(en.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return list;
                    list = new List<T>();
                }
            }

            if (list.Any())
                yield return list;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
var input = new[]{ 's', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'w', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 's', 'p', 'a', 'c', 'e', 's' };
var result = input.GroupWhile(x => x != ' ')
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you might be looking for something like this:

```
List<char> list = "some string with spaces".ToList();

List<List<char>> lists = list.Aggregate(new List<List<char>>() { new List<char>() },
    (a, e) => { if (e == ' ') a.Add(new List<char>()); else a.Last().Add(e); return a; });
```

I expect this to be just a tiny bit faster than the deferred execution `yield` answers, but some of the [`List<T>.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1) extra memory allocations can be avoided with 
[`List<T>.GetRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39) or 
[`List<T>.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eb2b9x8):

```
static List<List<T>> spliT<T>(this List<T> list, T separator = default(T), int start = 0)
{
    var lists = new List<List<T>>();

    for (int i = start; i < list.Count; i++)
        if (list[i].Equals(separator))
        {
            lists.Add(list.GetRange(start, i - start));
            start = i + 1;
        }

    lists.Add(list.GetRange(start, list.Count - start));
    return lists;
}
```

Comment: Why would you 'expect this to be just a tiny bit faster than the deferred execution `yield` answers'?  Can you elaborate because I don't have any reason to think that is the case.  Both of these solutions suffer from the same problem; they eagerly load the source data.  You have no idea what the source data is, you cannot know if it fits in memory.  What if the consumer of your extension method only intends to `Take` the first `n` elements.  Your method will still generate the entire list.

Comment: Because of the "I want it to to split into list of lists:", and that would be closer to the string.Split behaviour. My guess is that `.ToList` will be used on your extension to get the desired result, so I had it originally as "faster than using `.ToList` on the deferred execution `yield` answers" but shortened it before posting.